# Stop Spring Boot from loading @Configuration file from dependency module (jar)

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm implementing a Spring boot application with a dependency to another spring module (jar) containing an @Configuration (AmcConfiguration.class) file I do NOT want loaded into the context. I've tried many variations of exclude examples 
a few of which are as follows:

```
//exclude problem configuration class
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={AmcConfiguration.class})
```

and...

```
//exclude problem bean from within problem configuration class
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = IAmsClient.class))
```

and...

```
//exclude problem configuration class package
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.prot.mtrx.amc.config.*"))
```

Also, I've made sure there are no package naming collisions.

- spring boot root = "com.prot.am.*
- dependency = "com.prot.mtrx.amc.*"

I've been searching examples for a few days now and am running out of options. I went down the auto-configuration path but that seems much too complicated a solution to tell spring boot to not run one simple configuration class.

From my logs, it looks like it might be embedded tomcat:

```
DEBUG o.a.tomcat.util.digester.Digester -   New match='mbeans-descriptors/mbean/operation/parameter'
DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\TestSuite\workspace-dev\MAMClient\target\classes\com\prot\mtrx\amc\config\AmcConfiguration.class]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If the jar has a different package than your Spring Boot application class, your component scan will not pick it up (since by default it scans the same package and it's subpackages). I think there might be either another component scan, or somewhere it is explicitly imported. Have you checked if this might be the case? Another option is that other jar is a starter which automatically pick up configuration (is there a spring.factories file under META-INF)? Also are you sure, it is the configuration you don't want (have you checked the FQN)?

Comment: - Packages are different. 
- Other component scan seems likely, I'm not able to find it, debug logging is insane. I can break at bean creation, but I'm not finding anything useful down through the stack. Any tips here would be helpful.
- Nobody explicit calls, as it works when I comment out bean definition.
- The dependent jar only has classes, properties and a META-INF folder with maven with MANIFEST.MF
- I can comment out either the bean definition or the @Configuration annotation to solve the problem, so it really does feel like spring boot is doing this on its own.

Comment: Updated to add log entry.

Comment: Tomcat loading Spring beans would be quite strange. Is that log entry the only place in your debug log, where your `AmcConfiguration.class` is found?

Comment: No love yet for this problem!!! What I did to solve was move the particular configuration out of Java and into a context xml file so it isn't picked up by parent project's package scans. I Hate it! But that is what I'm stuck with. Thanks for you help so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the code: make the Configuration turn-on-and-offable

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("some-property")
```

This worked for me in spring-boot with tomcat.

Of course, you can override beans provided in the configuration with beans that do nothing by setting...

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

then provide your own implementations. This used to be the default behavior in Spring, but now requires that property for previous behavior.

However, creating replacement beans is flakey: the original beans get constructed before they are overridden which may have side effects & this approach is a moving target, not ideal.

The fact that

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={AmcConfiguration.class})
```

doesn't work, strikes me as a bug, maybe raise it as one? JavaDocs suggest it should.

```
Exclude specific auto-configuration classes such that they will never be applied.
```